# SQLAlchemy Query only compares strings up to a certain point

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Context:**

Im programming an API in python where I use tokens for authetication.

Table definition

```
class UserSessionModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_session"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(UserModel.id), nullable=False)
    token = Column(String(300), nullable=False)
    login_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    logout_date = Column(DateTime)
    expire_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

**Problem:**

Those tokens tend to be quite long (well above 100 characters). Storing the into the Database is no problem, also getting the entry back with a simple SELECT statement is no problem

```
SELECT * FROM user_session WHERE user_session.token = {token};
```

The problem arises when using the SQLAlchemy Query. The codes looks like this:

```
response = self.database_session.query(UserSessionModel).filter(token == token).all()
```

When I now have fairly similar tokens in the database like the following two:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoic3RyaW5nIiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoiMjAyMi0wNS0wNyAxNTo1MDoyMy44MzAxMzEifQ.o0m4LjOb4Jq_z5Y3jQeG7I15_smtY-hVSo2fQpkxM94

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoic3RyaW5nIiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoiMjAyMi0wNS0wNyAxNTo1MTo0OS44NjY1MzYifQ.fOODf6wXCyhN9OyLW1mSzKhZk1-5XIGNdbN57vaeN2c

The code returns both of those entries even though I'm only searching for one of them. My suspicion is that the query only compares the strings up to a certain point.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make sure that the SQLAlchemy Query compares the strings to the end and then only return one entry in case of the example above?

Comment: Please provide table definition, the actual query run and the results including the incorrect token.

Comment: Idk what u mean by the actual query run, the above code is literally what I do, I plug in one of the tokens in there and get bot database entries back from the database, probably since they are so similar. the tokens given as an example are also the actual tokens that are causing the problem. Other than that I edited the post with the table definition.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB with the SQLAlchemy ORM. No it hasnt, the database is completely up to date with the schema in python code.

Comment: Can you add `echo=True` to `create_engine` and add the resulting sql query to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.filter()` appears to be invalid. `token == token` will always be true so your filter will return all rows.

`.filter(UserSessionModel.token == token)` should work, but note that `session.query()` and `.filter()` are considered legacy in SQLAlchemy 1.4+ so the preferred incantation would be

```py
token =  "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoic3RyaW5nIiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoiMjAyMi0wNS0wNyAxNTo1MDoyMy44MzAxMzEifQ.o0m4LjOb4Jq_z5Y3jQeG7I15_smtY-hVSo2fQpkxM94"
results = database_session.scalars(
    select(UserSessionModel).where(UserSessionModel.token == token)
).all()
```

Comment: ok, so it was just a dumb mistake on my part, I just forgot to declare the class in the filter. Also thanks for the heads up on the up-to-date version on how to use it.